# How to find hotspot in performance of Oracle stored procedure

Tags: oracle, performance, stored-procedures

we know that one of the stored procedures is taking too much time in execution - having very complex workflow. which tool/method can be used to find hot spot of stored procedure ?

Comment: AWR.  ASH.  dbms_profiler.  Query v$sqlstats.  Trace the session and run tkprof.  Or the old standby of writing entries to a log table.  Lots of options to choose from.

Comment: Thank you @JustinCave for response. Let me explore it